# Is it okay to use persian utf-8 characters in our urls?

Tags: url, seo

It's best for SEO purposes that we use the main page keywords in our urls
For example stackoverflow uses this technique too.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/show-utf8-characters-in-console
```

I wonder if it's okay to use something like:

```
http://www.mobadele.com/categories/طلا-نفره
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. Officially you have to URL-encode them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

I am not sure how far the implementation of IRI 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier is, 
It may work in reality, but I have ran into all kind of trouble with Russian characters in URL's and query strings so I got rid of them.

Answer (score 2):

this question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865020/is-it-good-idea-to-use-url-names-with-special-characters/3967220#3967220

Comment: i.e.: http://www.facesaerch.com/f/%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7-%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%87

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: not if you want to follow the rules.

[RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) describes the required encoding and the rationale in section 2.2:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special
>   characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and reserved
>   characters used for their reserved
>   purposes may be used unencoded within
>   a URL.

Comment: The current specification is [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986).

Comment: Expect this to change, though; ICANN's working hard on [Internationalized Domain Names](http://www.icann.org/en/topics/idn/), which by their nature would require an update to the rules for URIs.